# Build a pyramid of balls using the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm having difficulties replicating the pyramid below on the canvas.

[image]

I'm struggling with the math portion on how to draw a new ball on each new line. Here is my code so far.

```
<canvas id="testCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

<script>
    // Access canvas element and its context
    const canvas = document.getElementById('testCanvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const x = canvas.width;
    const y = canvas.height;
    const radius = 10;
    const diamater = radius * 2;
    const numOfRows = canvas.width / diamater;

    function ball(x, y) {
        context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        context.fillStyle = "#FF0000"; // red
        context.fill();
    }

    function draw() {
        for (let i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
                ball(
                    //Pos X
                    (x / 2),
                    //Pos Y
                    diamater * (i + 1)
                );
            }
        }
        ball(x / 2, y);

        context.restore();
    }

    draw();

</script>
```

I've been stuck on this problem for a while. I appreciate any assistance you can provide.
Thank you.

Comment: If you were going to do it "by hand" (e.g., draw it), how would you determine where each row of balls started? What thing(s) would that starting `x` rely on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you can approach this problem is by breaking it down into one step at a time.

1. On (1)st row draw 1 circle
2. On (2)nd row draw 2 circles
3. On (3)rd row draw 3 circles

And so on...

Then you have to figure out where to draw each circle. That also you can break down into steps.

1st-row 1st circle in the center (width)

2nd-row 1st circle in the center minus diameter

2nd-row 2nd circle in the center plus diameter

and so on.

Doing this way you will find a pattern to convert into 2 for loops.

Something like this:

```
//1st row 1st circle
ball(w/2,radius * 1, red);

//2nd row 1st circle
ball(w/2 - radius,radius * 3, blue); 
//2nd row 2nd circle
ball(w/2 + radius,radius * 3, blue);
```

The code below shows each step how each ball is drawn. I have also done few corrections to take care of the numberOfRows.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('testCanvas');
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const w = canvas.width;
const h = canvas.height;
const radius = 10;
const diamater = radius * 2;
const numOfRows = Math.min(h / diamater, w / diamater);
const red = "#FF0000";
const blue = "#0000FF";

var k = 1;

function ball(x, y, color) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fill();
  }, (k++) * 250);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= numOfRows; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    var y = (i * radius * 2) - radius;
    var x = (w / 2) - ((i * radius) + radius) + (j * diamater);
    ball(x, y, i % 2 ? red : blue);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="testCanvas" 
        width="300" height="180" 
        style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Himanshu!!! I love how you approached the problem and your solution is awesome. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that the circle do not touch. I am not sure if you need or want them to but as this presented an interesting problem I create this answer.

### Distance between stacked circles.

The distance between rows can be calculated using the right triangle as shown in the following image

[image]

Where R is the radius of the circle and D is the distance between rows.

```
   D = ((R + R) ** 2 - R ** 2) ** 0.5;
```

With that we can get the number of rows we can fit given a radius as

```
  S = (H - R * 2) / D;
```

Where `H` is the height of the canvas and `S` is the number of rows.

#### Example

Given a radius fits as many rows as possible into the give canvas height.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const W = canvas.width, H = canvas.height, CENTER = W / 2;
const cols = ["#E80", "#0B0"];
draw();
function fillPath(path, x, y, color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
    ctx.fill(path);
}
function draw() {
    const R = 10;
    const D = ((R * 2) ** 2 - R ** 2) ** 0.5;
    const S = (H - R * 2) / D | 0;
    const TOP = R + (H - (R * 2 + D * S)) / 2;  // center horizontal
    const circle = new Path2D();
    circle.arc(0, 0, R, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    var y = 0, x;
    while (y <= S) {
        x = 0;
        const LEFT = CENTER - (y * R);
        while (x <= y) {
            fillPath(circle, LEFT + (x++) * R * 2, TOP + y * D, cols[y % 2]);  
        }
        y ++;
    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"  width="300" height="180"></canvas>
```

### Radius to fit n rows of stacked circles

Or if you have the height `H` and the number of rows `S` you want to fit. As shown in next image.

[image]

We want to find `R` given `H` and `S` we rearrange for `H` and solve the resulting quadratic with

```
ss = S * S - 2 * S + 1;
a = 4 / ss;
b = -4 * H / ss;
c = H * H / ss;
R = (-b-(b*b - 4 * a * c) ** 0.5) / (2 * a); // the radius
```

#### Example

Given the number of rows (number input) calculates the radius that will fit that number of rows

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const W = canvas.width, H = canvas.height, CENTER = W / 2;
rowsIn.addEventListener("input", draw)
const cols = ["#DD0", "#0A0"];
draw();
function fillPath(path, x, y, color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
    ctx.fill(path);
}
function draw() {
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,W,H);
    const S = Number(rowsIn.value);
    const ss = S * S - 2 * S + 1;
    const a = 4 / ss - 3, b = -4 * H / ss, c = H * H / ss;
    const R = (- b - ((b * b - 4 * a * c) ** 0.5)) / (2 * a); // the radius
    const TOP = R;
    const D = ((R * 2) ** 2 - R ** 2) ** 0.5;
    //const S = (H - R * 2) / D;
    const circle = new Path2D();
    circle.arc(0, 0, R, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    var y = 0, x;
    while (y < S) {
        x = 0;
        const LEFT = CENTER - (y * R);
        while (x <= y) {
            fillPath(circle, LEFT + (x++) * R * 2, TOP + y * D, cols[y % 2]);  
        }
        y ++;
    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"  width="300" height="180"></canvas>
<input type="number" id="rowsIn"  min="3" max="12" value="3">Rows
```